# Split Partition is giving error when partitioning

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, partition

I have a partitioned table where the definition during creation was

```
  PARTITION  BY RANGE (CREATED_DT)
(
PARTITION p2016
   VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2016','dd-mon-yyyy')),   
PARTITION p2017
   VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2017','dd-mon-yyyy')),  
PARTITION p2018
   VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2018','dd-mon-yyyy')),
PARTITION p2019
   VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2019','dd-mon-yyyy')),
PARTITION p 
    VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)   
)
```

Now I want to split p2016 into 3 partitions where I am issuing the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE BKP_COST_EVENT SPLIT PARTITION p2016 INTO
( PARTITION p14 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2015','dd-MON-yyyy')),
  PARTITION p13 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2014','dd-MON-yyyy')),
  PARTITION p2016_1 );
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Error report -
ORA-14080: partition cannot be split along the specified high bound
14080. 00000 -  "partition cannot be split along the specified high bound"
*Cause:    User attempted to split a partition along a bound which
           either collates higher than that of the partition to be split or
           lower than that of a partition immediately preceding the one
           to be split
*Action:   Ensure that the bound along which a partition is to be split
           collates lower than that of the partition to be split and
           higher that that of a partition immediately preceding the one
           to be split
```

What am I doing wrong and how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of the partitions given in your ALTER TABLE:

```
ALTER TABLE BKP_COST_EVENT SPLIT PARTITION p2016 INTO
( PARTITION p13 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2014','dd-MON-yyyy')),
  PARTITION p14 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2015','dd-MON-yyyy')),
  PARTITION p2016_1 );
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=25885f93b0f368510f0bff55ef7311ed)